# How to call An activity class from a service class

Tags: android

In my app there is a service class and need to call an activity class from that service class,but it each time while calling the activity class its show me a message that 
application is not responding ,and below is my code..

```
public class MyAlarmService_Movie extends Service {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        Intent in=new Intent().setClass(MyAlarmService.this,Reminder.class);
        startActivity(in);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Give `in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` before starting the intent.