# Run activity B in the background when i start my app (A is my launcher activity)

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activities A & B. Activity A is launcher activity & I want to Run Activity B in the background when i launch my app. I dont want to go on activity B. I just want to run in background. Also I don't want change this activity to service. 
My Question is that Can we run a activity in background? if yes then please give me some sample of code how can we run?

Comment: Why Activity, its any requirement

Comment: You can't do it. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11102383/7011814

Comment: Describe your problem, please.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you include any requirements for the problem at hand.

Comment: Ok.. is there any way to call complete activity in the service class? @AlexShevelev

Comment: @ScottS  I want to run my main activity in the background.. My main activity have a map and i created fences on the map.. when user enter into the fence circle a notification pop up into the device.. Now i want to do a button enable (when user enter) and disable (when user exit) from fence. I dont want to show user a map i just want to show directly an activity which have 3 buttons. I hope now you all can understand which i want..

Comment: Main activity functions working perfectly. I just want to run main activity into background not on foreground..

Answer (score 1):

You cannot really run an Activity on background! When an activity is not on foreground it gets to onStop and then the system could terminate it, to release resources, by onDestroy method! see [Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html)

Comment: Can i run this activity through service class??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015507/how-to-call-an-activity-class-from-a-service-class

Comment: Thank you bro!! Now I want to run complete activity in background through service.. Is there any way or link?

Comment: I want to run my main activity in the background.. My main activity have a map and i created fences on the map.. when user enter into the fence circle a notification pop up into the device.. Now i want to do a button enable (when user enter) and disable (when user exit) from fence. I dont want to show user a map i just want to show directly an activity which have 3 buttons. I hope now you all can understand which i want..

Comment: Nope, But my question why activity, activity is create for foreground, iyou can use service, asynctask or job for background when your task is finish get call back in Activity

Comment: You are asking for wrong thing, when you set notification set callback activity that you want to show

Comment: First mine task was to show on activity that's why i created activity now his new requirement this main activity should be invisible for user..

Comment: Yes thanks you got my point.. But how to invisible main activity for user??

Comment: From notification, if yes then share code how you call notification

Comment: can i inbox you??

Comment: https://zeeshanfuuastcs.blogspot.com/b/post-preview?token=xpOU_l8BAAA.QY4mu8RCROkG_xLQQ1F-uxI3pEYiAbXo9yKZalNnIUieIuBuvusq5QPIph36Ksc8ztQ0tOHylRehNceYliRYlw.uQfiBs4WjJY4_HZ0BNIMfw&postId=2852912898695631903&type=POST

Comment: Okay, what method??